# How I can bind a value to a clicked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dynamically create checkboxes in item forms, when I submit a form in item forms, I get an array of checkbox IDs. How can I either bind true / false to these IDs or overwrite the object, create a new one or something else by clicking on the checkbox? How to understand which checkbox was clicked and bind a value to it true / false?

```
const [checkboxData, setCheckboxData] = useState(undefined);
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
        const data = await request(`/document-type/typeDocuments`, { method: 'get', cancelTokenKey: 'typeDocuments' });
        if (data) { setCheckboxData(data.content); }
   })();
}, []);

function onChangeCheckbox(checkedValues) {
    setCheckboxData(prevState => {
        prevState.map(item => ...)
    }) // tried this, but then when you click on the checkbox everything breaks
}

<Form
    onFinish={onFormFinish}
    onFinishFailed={onFormFailed}
>
    <Form.Item
         name="typesDocuments"
         valuePropName="checked"
    >
        <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: '100%' }}>
             <Row>
                 {checkboxData?.map(item => <Col span={12}><Checkbox key={item?.id} value={item?.id} onChange={onChangeCheckbox}>{item?.Name}</Checkbox></Col>)}
             </Row>
        </Checkbox.Group>
     </Form.Item>

     <Form.Item>
         <Space style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'end' }}>
              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit"> {intl("modal-btn-ok")} </Button>
         </Space>
     </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

For ease of viewing, I created an example of a project in a
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lamport-9w6s3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Where is your `onChangeCheckbox` function?

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite the object, create a new one or something else"? Do you want specific array of objects? If so you should just map values to desired objects in `onFormFinish`

Comment: @Andy add `onChangeCheckbox`, tried this, but then when you click on the checkbox everything breaks

Comment: You mean something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bird-inxql You just need to track which items have been selected, and you can do that by their ID since thats a unique identifier on the checkbox's data set

Comment: @FilipSeman does not matter, my main goal, when clicking on any of the checkboxes, bind true / false to it and send the id of the selected checkbox and its state to the database

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, something like that, but how to make sure that it does not overwrite the object with each click and add a property to it? using prevState?

Comment: you can always extend the existing state if you'd like

Comment: @eugenes So you don't care about the submit state, but you want to send request on every check?

Comment: @FilipSeman I want to send the checkbox id and its state, if several checkboxes are selected, so that the object is not overwritten after each click, but new values are added